# What is the correct SQL DataType to represent my Object?

Tags: sql-server-2008, char, ascii, varchar, extended-ascii

My object is a string, implemented as an array of 1-50 [US-ASCII data](http://www.asciitable.com/) characters.

1. What SQL Data Type should I use to represent this in my database table?

   - I am using SQL Server Express 2008. (Does that matter?)
2. Does representing [Extended ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) require a different datatype than representing  [Standard ASCII](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a variable length US-ASCII field (up to 50 characters), use `VARCHAR(50)`. If you want to use Unicode, you need to use `NVARCHAR(50)`.

> varchar [ ( n | max ) ]
>
> Variable-length, non-Unicode character data. n can be a value from 1 through 8,000. max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes. The storage size is the actual length of data entered + 2 bytes. The data entered can be 0 characters in length. The ISO synonyms for varchar are char varying or character varying.

And:

> Objects that use char or varchar are assigned the default collation of the database, unless a specific collation is assigned using the COLLATE clause. The collation controls the code page that is used to store the character data.

---

> nvarchar [ ( n | max ) ]
>
> Variable-length Unicode character data. ncan be a value from 1 through 4,000. max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes. The storage size, in bytes, is two times the number of characters entered + 2 bytes. The data entered can be 0 characters in length. The ISO synonyms for nvarchar are national char varying and national character varying.